# ifstream initialization error- Error Reading Characters

Tags: c++, ifstream

```
    #include "Stdafx.h"
    #include "FishTracker.h"
    #include <string>
    #include "Utils.h"
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;
    int main()
    {
        std::string videopath;
        videopath = "E:\\TUKLNUST\\fishdata2\\Damo\\AR2-6\\Tetraodontidae_Lagocephalus_sceleratus_AD\\00001\\";

        ifstream str;
        str.open((videopath + DATA_TXT).c_str());
        if (str.is_open())
        {
            cout << "file is open.";
        }
    }
```

file is open but `str` is this.

```
+       str {_Filebuffer={_Set_eback=0xcccccccc <Error reading characters of string.> _Set_egptr=0xcccccccc <Error reading characters of string.> ...} }    std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >
```

**Configs**:

*win32, Debug*

*Visual Studio 2013*

Comment: You cannot use these statements outside of a function.

Comment: yes i am using them in main

Comment: Post real code please!

Comment: Post a real question, too! Seriously, please go and study the posting guidelines, many of the thing you did wrong in your question are explained there.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include "FishTracker.h"
#include <string>
#include "Utils.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    std::string videopath;
        videopath = "E:\\TUKLNUST\\fishdata2\\Damo\\AR2-6\\Tetraodontidae_Lagocephalus_sceleratus_AD\\00001\\";

        ifstream str;
        str.open((videopath + "DATA_TXT").c_str());
        if (str.is_open())
    {
        cout << "file is open.";
    }
```

}

Comment: @OmerJR, I add the **"DATA_TXT"**, you just did it like a variable.

Comment: I have defined it  as
`#define DATA_TXT "Data.txt"`
in FishTracker.h